# D3.js reading Lat Long coordinates from csv into Google Map

Tags: google-maps, csv, d3.js, latitude-longitude, points

I am trying to get dots onto a google map using D3 and a csv file. i seem to be able to read the lat long coordinates properly but they will not draw anywhere on the map.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), 
{
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.654835520000063, -105.01942651999994),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) 
{
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {
d3.select("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cy", function(d) 
    {
        return [d.longitude, d.latitude][0];
    })
    .attr("cx", function(d) 
    {
        return [d.longitude, d.latitude][1];
    })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "blue");     
}
overlay.setMap(map);
});
```

Comment: You need to project the coordinates. Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the overlay.onAdd function. onAdd() is called once after overlay.setMap() is called with a valid map. If you don't specify anything to be implemented in onAdd() (which is an empty function by default), nothing will happen. Therefore, you should use onAdd to initialize the DOM overlay elements.

For example, the code shared above uses the following implementation: 
    `overlay.onAdd = function() {
    var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");
    //more code here
    }`

the layer variable is what you want to look at.